# Why is each element of my generic list the same? (VB)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

With the following code:

```
Dim albums As New List(Of Album)
Dim album As New Album
Dim s1 As String

For i = 1 To 10
  album.AlbumId = i
  album.Title = "Album " & i
  albums.Add(album)
Next

For Each a In albums
  s1 = a.Title
Next
```

Checking s1 at every iteration in the “For Each” loop shows the same title.

Album is defined like this:

```
Public Class Album

  Private mAlbumId As Integer
  Public Property AlbumId() As Integer
    Get
      Return mAlbumId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
      mAlbumId = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Private mTitle As String
  Public Property Title() As String
    Get
      Return mTitle
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      mTitle = value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

What am I missing so that I can store and retrieve 10 different elements?

Comment: You created only *one* Album object.  You cannot expect to end up with 10 different objects.  Check your favorite VB.NET language book about the difference between reference and value types.

Comment: 1: How do you check the s1 String? You've only showed us how you set it. 2: A for loop without delay like your s1 loop will complete almost emediatelly. 3. Since you ONLY SET the s1 text to the current album's title, it will always display the latest album. Check out my answer for more info...

Comment: In answer to Vincent, I just set a breakpoint on Next and checked the value as I cycled through.  If I would have output the results, your code below would be great, but also see my comment after that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Album` is a reference type - all classes are reference types.  Assignment semantics of value and reference types are different.  Value types (like double, integer, etc) are represented by variables that contain their values.

Reference types only contain a reference (or pointer) to an object of their type.  When you write :

```
 Dim album As New Album
```

you are allocating a variable `album` and are pointing to a newly created instance of the `Album` class.  (By the way, since VB is not case sensitive, it is a bad idea to have variables with the same name and different case! You should consider calling the variable something like `_album` or `anAlbum` or anything with a different spelling).

In any event, when you then go on to do :

```
For i = 1 To 10
  album.AlbumId = i
  album.Title = "Album " & i
  albums.Add(album)
Next
```

You are changing the properties of the single `Album` instance you have created and are repeatedly adding the same album to the list.  The list ends up with ten references to the same album object since you have not created more than one of them.

What you need to do is create a new instance each time :

```
dim anAlbum as Album   'do not create one yet!
For i = 1 To 10
  anAlbum = New Album  'instead, make a new one each time
  anAlbum.AlbumId = i
  anAlbum.Title = "Album " & i
  Albums.Add(anAlbum)
Next
```

Each time you write :

```
anAlbum = New Album
```

you are creating a new `Album` object and are overwriting the reference in the variable `anAlbum` to point to the newly created object.  Adding it to the list, then, adds the new reference to the new object.

---

Now, for simple data structures **of value types** with a reasonable size an alternative to using a `Class` is to use a `Structure` instead.  `Structure`s are value types and, as such, are copied when assigned (unlike `Classes` or other reference types).  If you *want* value type assignment semantics, and do not care about "classy" things like polymorphism or inheritance, then you can instead redefine your `Album` class as a structure as so :

```
 Public Structure Album

    Private mAlbumId As Integer
    Public Property AlbumId() As Integer
        Get
            Return mAlbumId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            mAlbumId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private mTitle As String
    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return mTitle
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mTitle = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Structure
```

And then this sort of thing will work as you expect:

```
 Dim AnAlbum As New Album

 For i = 1 To 10
     AnAlbum.AlbumId = i
     AnAlbum.Title = "Album " & i
     albums.Add(AnAlbum)
 Next
```

Selecting between a `Class` and a `Structure` is an important part of the design process but is rather too deep a topic to treat fully here, however.  Be careful that a `Structure` that contains reference types can be tricky since under assignment its value members will copy but its reference members will continue to point to the same objects!

---

For further reading, perhaps start at the documentation :

[MSDN - Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)

Comment: Worked great as you posted above. Pretty simpleton error and I really needed the outside look. Thx!  I think using Class is much better than Structure, but will certainly keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do these changes to your code:

```
Dim albums As New List(Of Album)
Dim s1 As String = ""

For i = 1 To 10
  Dim Albm As New Album 'Define the album here instead to be sure that nothing goes wrong
  Albm.AlbumId = i
  Albm.Title = "Album " & i
  albums.Add(Albm)
Next

For Each a In albums
  s1 = s1 & a.Title & Environment.NewLine 'This will list all the albums in one string
  'Just doing s1 = a.Title will result in the string changing ONLY to the latest album's Title.
  'Doing this will list all albums in one string
Next
```

The "For Each a ..." loop above will give this result:

> Album 1
>
> Album 2
>
> Album 3
>
> Album 4
>
> Album 5
>
> Album 6
>
> Album 7
>
> Album 8
>
> Album 9
>
> Album 10

Comment: Just making sure, but in the For loop above when the Add is invoked shouldn't it be for albums and not Albm?